# Vuejs ajax call not mapping changes to underlying html table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am making simple ajax call with vuejs and axios:

```
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app1',
  data: {
    test: []
  },
  methods: {    
    setAJAX: function () {
      axios.get('/Departments/GetDepartments/').then(response => this.test = response.data.listBACAET);
    }
  }
});
```

Why is this working:

```
setAJAX: function () {
      axios.get('/Departments/GetDepartments/').then(response => this.test = response.data.listBACAET);
    }
```

But this is not working, changes are not mapped into table (this.test is undefined):

```
setAJAX: function () {
      axios.get('/Departments/GetDepartments/').then(function(response){this.test = response.data.listBACAET});
    }
```

Comment: how is `setAJAX` being called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the way arrow functions work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

When using an arrow function, `this` is implicitly bound to `this` of the enclosing scope, which is, in your case, the vue instance on which the method is called. 
So you're setting the data of your view model, which works.

When using a std. function, there is no `this` in the scope, hence the error. To use a std. function, you need to define a closure for your view model like this:

```
setAJAX: function () {
  let vm = this
  axios.get('...').then( function(response) {
    vm.test = response.data.listBACAET
  });
}
```

Comment: There is only one thing I don't understand - axios is function (typeof axios == 'function'). How can this call be made: axios.get('...') ? It seems like function inside function.